# Error while deploying Laravel Website with Docker Compose

Tags: laravel, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I tried to deploy my Laravel website with docker-compose(**docker-compose.yml**), once i run my compose file the website throws an error as

`could not find driver (SQL: select * from ...)`
[image]

I went through many articles and I can't find a solution to the issue. Can anyone please help out clearly

Docker Compose Version: 3.2
Docker Engine Version: 19.*

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.2'

services:

  wserver:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: web-nginx
    ports:
      - 4080:80
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /root/website/files
        target: /var/www/html
      - type: bind
        source: /root/website/nginx/conf.d/
        target: /etc/nginx/conf.d/

  phpweb:
    build:
        context: ./php/
    container_name: web-phpfpm
    ports:
      - 4900:9000
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /root/website/files
        target: /var/www/html

  dbserver:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: web-mariadb
    ports:
      - 4306:3306
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /root/website/mariadb/
        target: /var/lib/mysql/
      - type: bind
        source: /root/website/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
        target: /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
    environment:
      TZ: "Asia/Kolkata"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql




Docker File:

FROM php:7.4-fpm

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli
```

Comment: share your `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/17GtowkgfqfKWm1xtbVAJOW42JjGwe87yQqlLS57rIqc/edit?usp=sharing

I have Shared the docker-compose.yml file via google drive with the mentioned link